# Weekly reboot of network switches

Tags: networking, switch, reboot

Seeking opinions on a perplexing IT practice: a company regularly reboots customers' switches weekly. This seems counterintuitive and could lead to issues, especially with multiple connected devices.

Abrupt disconnections during network communication may increase the risk of processes entering the 'D state' or applications lingering in the 'CLOSE WAIT' state.

Furthermore, frequent restarts might contribute to additional wear and tear on the networking equipment, sparking concerns about the long-term reliability and stability of the devices.

While reboots are scheduled during low-traffic periods, the overall practice seems unusual. I understand the need for updates and troubleshooting, but this frequency raises questions. What are your thoughts on such a routine?

Comment: There are people who do not understand that modern switches bridge frames in hardware. Older bridges were software-based. I have been told by a network manager with a server background that he does something similar because of memory leaks. When I explained that modern switches are hardware-based, he told me that I did not know what I was talking about. I know it used to be a practice among some to reboot servers on a regular basis because older OSes and/or applications had memory leaks, but I have had busy switches up and running for years with no problem.

Comment: Such a practice might be from cargo-cult system administrators ; no real understanding on how modern IT works but since they already did regular reboots  in the Stone Age of IT following that same pattern should still be relevant today. - But soliciting opinion based answers is off topic.

Comment: Although organizations that equate and blindly strive for high uptimes probably don’t reboot frequently enough (many updates still require a reboot to take effect) in general you reboot when necessary not only because you have schedule

Answer (score 5):

Unless there are known issues with the models/firmware version in use, that doesn't make sense. The cost (connectivity disruption, potential startup problems) by far outweighs the potential benefit.

The only benefit I can think of is reclaiming leaked memory (as Ron's comment mentions). While memory leaks are not at all unheard of on long-running servers, network devices with substantially less complex software installations very rarely suffer from it. Memory usage can be reasonably monitored by common SNMP practices.